# Sorting 3 dimensional array at 2nd level based on 3rd level values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I am using the Google Calendar API to pull data from multiple calendars.  I am creating an array so I can format the display of the data.  I am having trouble sorting the data so events will appear in the proper order.

My primary sort is on `datetime` ASC.  If the two datetimes are equal I want to sort on `alldayflag` DESC.  I only want it sorted within each date.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Array 
( 
[2016-01-29] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 29 
                [time] => 8:30 am 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-29T08:30:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
        [1] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 29 
                [time] => 12:00 am 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-29T00:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 1 
            ) 
        [2] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 29 
                [time] => 2:00 pm 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-29T14:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
        [3] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 29 
                [time] => 10:00 am 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-29T10:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
        [4] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 29 
                [time] => 12:00 pm 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-29T12:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
    ) 
[2016-01-30] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 30 
                [time] => 4:00 pm 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-30T16:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
        [1] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 30 
                [time] => 5:00 pm 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-30T17:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
        [2] => Array 
            ( 
                [date] => January 30 
                [time] => 11:00 am 
                [datetime] => 2016-01-30T11:00:00-06:00 
                [alldayflag] => 0 
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

I have tried using `array_multisort()`.  I get the proper sorting results however I also get the error message:

> Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent in sort-array.php on line XXX

```
$getBeginDate = '2016-01-29';
$getEndDate = '2016-01-31';

$getCurrentDate = $getBeginDate;

while(strtotime($getCurrentDate) < strtotime($getEndDate)) {

    foreach ($list[$getCurrentDate] as $key => $row){
         $datetime[$key] = $row['datetime'];
         $alldayflag[$key] = $row['alldayflag'];
    }

    array_multisort($datetime, SORT_ASC, $alldayflag, SORT_DESC, $list[$getCurrentDate]);

    $getCurrentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($getCurrentDate . " +1 day"));

}
```

I have also tried `uasort()`.  It doesn't sort properly at all.

```
uasort($list, 'sortCriteria');

function sortCriteria($array, $key) {
    if(strtotime($a['datetime']) == strtotime($b['datetime'])) {
        if($a['allday'] < $b['allday']) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return (strtotime($a['datetime']) < strtotime($b['datetime'])) ? -1 : 1;

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_multisort` is definitely the way that you want to go. I have an untested answer for you, so may I be smited by the wrath of the community if it's an incorrect guess, but it looks like you're running into a closure issue, or rather the lack thereof. This should fix your issue:

```
...
while(strtotime($getCurrentDate) < strtotime($getEndDate)) {

$datetime = [];
$alldayflag = [];
foreach ($list[$getCurrentDate] as $key => $row){
...
```

My guess from the error you mentioned is that if you dumped `$datetime` before the multisort it would have 5 items in it the first time and 5 items in it the second time.

```
first_dump => '29th', '29th', '29th', '29th', '29th'
second_dump => '30th', '30th', '30th', '29th', '29th'
```

Or something similar to this. What's happening is $datetime is persisting through the first round of the while loop into the second time. Which is bombing out your multisort the second time because there are only 3 items and not 5.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that makes complete sense.  I made the change and it solved my problem.  Fantastic!  That is such an easy solution.  Thanks for your quick response.  This was one of those times I just needed someone fresh to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).
You can then use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to compare the 'datetime'.
Then if two datetimes are equal, you can compare the 'alldayflag'.

For example:

```
function sortCriteria($a, $b)
{
    $aDateTime = new DateTime($a['datetime']);
    $bDateTime = new DateTime($b['datetime']);

    if ($aDateTime == $bDateTime) {
        return ($a['alldayflag'] > $b['alldayflag']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return ($aDateTime < $bDateTime) ? -1 : 1;
}

$getBeginDate = '2016-01-29';
$getEndDate = '2016-01-31';
$getCurrentDate = $getBeginDate;

while(strtotime($getCurrentDate) < strtotime($getEndDate)) {
    usort($list[$getCurrentDate], 'sortCriteria');
    $getCurrentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($getCurrentDate . " +1 day"));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DpoEm)

Comment: I see it working correctly on the sample data but it is not working on my live data for some reason.  I will look at this more to see if I can figure out what is going wrong.  I did find a solution with my array_multisort but I am interested in learning if this could be a solution as well.