# Sort an php array that is part of another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, php-5.6

I have an array like this

```
"entry a" => [
    "type": 3,
    "id": 1,
    "content" => [
        [
            "name" => "somename a",
            "date": => "2011-08-2"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "somename b",
            "date": => "2012-04-20"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "somename c",
            "date": => "2015-01-14"
        ],
    ]
],
 "entry b" => [
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2,
    "content" => [
        [
            "name" => "someothername a",
            "date": => "2011-01-6"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "someothername b",
            "date": => "2015-12-24"
        ],
        [
            "name" => "someothername c",
            "date": => "2016-01-01"
        ],
    ]
],
...
```

I want to sort just the "content" array, by date, of each entry. I tried the following;

```
        foreach ($cfArray as $cfEntry) {
            if($cfEntry['type'] == '3' && !is_null($cfEntry['content'])) {
                $content = $cfEntry['content'];
                uasort($content, function($a, $b) {
                    $a_end = strtotime($a['date']);
                    $b_end = strtotime($b['date']);
                    return ($a_end > $b_end) ? -1 : 1;
                });
                $cfEntry['content'] = $content;
            }
        }
```

If I compare $content before and after the sort, it has changed but my $cfArray does not change. Why is that? Is there another way to sort this?

Comment: Lock array multisort in stackoverflow. You question dublikate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097681/sorting-3-dimensional-array-at-2nd-level-based-on-3rd-level-values for example

Comment: why do you filter only items with `"type": 3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost working, and you can create it fully working with saving changed item to `$newCfArray` array with this sample:

```
$newCfArray = array();
foreach ($cfArray as $key => $cfEntry) {
    if($cfEntry['type'] == '3' && !is_null($cfEntry['content'])) {
        $content = $cfEntry['content'];
        uasort($content, function($a, $b) {
            $a_end = strtotime($a['date']);
            $b_end = strtotime($b['date']);
            return ($a_end > $b_end) ? -1 : 1;
        });
        $cfEntry['content'] = $content;
    }
    $newCfArray[$key] = $cfEntry;
}
$cfArray = $newCfArray;
```

Comment: Hey thank you! Works perfectly. I also noticed that `uasort` was wrong in my case. I now use `usort`. But that was a different problem. =)